# Make UserControl parent invalid when child has error

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have created a user control that functions as a simple file browser. What I would like to see is that the full user control is set to invalid when the textbox has an error.

I think it should be possible to get the result with WPF only...

```
<UserControl x:Class="WorldGenerator.Controls.FileBrowseControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignWidth="300"
             xmlns:wg="clr-namespace:WorldGenerator.Controls"
             xmlns:v="clr-namespace:WorldGenerator.Validation">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,10,0">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="FilePath">
                    <Binding.RelativeSource>
                        <RelativeSource AncestorType="wg:FileBrowseControl" Mode="FindAncestor"/>
                    </Binding.RelativeSource>
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <v:FileExistsValidationRule/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Click="BrowseButton_OnClick" Content="Browse..."/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Edit**: This is the usage of `FileBrowseControl` in a `Window`.

```
<Window>
    <FileBrowseControl/>
    <Button IsEnabled="{Binding BUT HOW DO I BIND TO FileBrowseControl.HasErrors?}"/>

</Window>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible by setting 'IsEnabled' property to `false`;
For example, there is UserControl called `userControl`. Then in your textBox validation logic you can set `IsEnabled` property of `userControl` to `false`:

Your xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataGridWpfApplication.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridWpfApplication"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Name="userControl">
    <Grid>            
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In code-behind you can set `IsEnabled` property to `false`:

```
private void SetIsEnabledProperty()
{
    userControl.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: I am actually looking for a way to bubble the fact that the whole user control is invalid so I can use that property (is invalid) as an external property to be bound on some other control.

Comment: @Marnix do you mean that your current `UserControl1` can be nested inside another `UserConrtol2` and you want to bubble an event from `UserControl1` if something wrong to handle this bubbling event into `UserControl1`?

Comment: I don't want to handle an event, I want to set UserControl2.IsValid to false when UserControl1 is invalid.

Comment: @Marnix could you write your exact XAML where `UserControl1` and `UserControl` are declared?

Comment: I added the usage of FileBrowseControl in Window in the question